# identifying large circle like white color in an image using python

Tags: python, opencv

I need suggestion with this two image.

Image A
[image]

Image B
[image]

I'm trying to identify if an image has an optic nerve glioma.

**Image A** represents that there is no abnormality, it has a smaller circle like white color on the image. while **Image B** has a larger one which has the optic nerve glioma. basically what I want to do is identify if the image has a larger circle white color compare to the standard basis which is the **Image A**

Any suggestion is a big help. Thanks guys!

Comment: If you have access to a large data set of labeled images it is rather simple to train up a classifier.

Comment: sorry I don't have one. by classifier what do you mean?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QfNvhPx5Px8

Comment: by building a classifier didn't the output will be same since they both have the same characteristics but only differ on size?

Comment: trying to detect the bright circle and to compare their size would be some kind of "hand crafted features classifier" while a deep neural network might be able to learn those and other features during the training.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using something like [Google Cloud Vision](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/labels) or [Azure image detection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure) or some other off the shelf service that does all the heavy lifting.

For example, here is with Azure where you can get the bounding rectangles of various shapes/objects in your image: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/concept-object-detection. From that I would see -- if all image sizes are standardized and the same -- the area of the bounding rectangle in the inner circle can give you a confidence score on whether the optic nerve glioma exists or not.

Comment: the size is not standard.

Comment: @AmyllaVimiar -- I would think that would be the first part of the task is to scale the size (i.e., radius of each input eye) to be the same. Once that's standardized I think using one of the image detection services might be very helpful. You cry try out Microsft's here: https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5adf991815e1060e6355ad44/operations/5e0cdeda77a84fcd9a6d3d0a/console

Answer (score 0):

Eye doc? There are infinite possibilities with machine learning algorithms and neural networks. You'll need to train an image classifier.

https://towardsdatascience.com/all-the-steps-to-build-your-first-image-classifier-with-code-cf244b015799

There's a link ^. If you're doing this for a large-scale project, I'd recommend hiring a developer. It can be done, but it ain't going to be easy except maybe for programmers who've been doing AI work.

Comment: Didn't building a classifier will provide same result when detecting image a and b? since they both have same characteristics?

Comment: They don't have the same characteristics. The epineurium appears thicker, and more importantly, the images differ in the size of the lighter-colored area - which is precisely where a classifier could function. It can measure the mean distance between the center of the optic nerve and the boundary of the lighter color of "normal" and diseased optic nerves, and then "learn" how to distinguish between them.

Comment: So if I built a classifier using CNN will that do the job? will that be able to classify and identify image a from image b?

Comment: You'll need a lot of modules besides that. What you're talking about is extraordinarily complex. Several months work of work probably, even borrowing heavily from open source projects developed at universities.

Comment: Just a thought. what about using a template matching for the image?

Comment: Matching images is a machine learning task either way. Unless you cropped the optic nerve itself and used the boundaries to detect abnormalities. It wouldn't sort neoplasms, though. I don't know what kind of variation is normal in the size of optic nerves from person to person. You could potentially do that with just color matching boundaries.